# Twitter integration in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: twitter, windows-phone-8.1, hammock

Twitter integration in Windows Phone 8 was done using Hammock nuget package. In Windows Phone 8.1 Hammock is not supported. Is there any other method to integrate twitter with the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq2Twitter does not use Hammock as far as i know:
https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/

It is quite well documented.

Or of you just want to share a status you can use the ShareStatusTask:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate "Sign in with with Twitter" button, then you can use a library I've developed
https://github.com/konradbartecki/TwitterAutherino

Let me know if you need some currently non-existent features